# Change shell script from ftp to sftp

Tags: shell

I have below shell script to get files from ftp server.
I need to change this script to point to same SFTP server ?
Can some one assist to change this script from ftp to sftp?

```
HOST='some.site.com'
USER='yourid'`enter code here`
PASSWD='yourpw'
FILE='file.txt'

ftp $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
user $USER
$PASSWD
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so complicated, just use the `sftp` binary instead of the `ftp`. The FTP commands stay exactly the same (it's still the FTP protocol, just over an encrypted connection), the user may be specified as a part of the SFTP's host argument:

```
sftp $USER@$HOST <<EOF
$PASSWD
put $FILE
quit
EOF
```